# MongoTimeoutError: name: 'MongoNetworkError', [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, docker, heroku

I have an i have app on Node.js. It works perfectly locally but when I try to deploy it in a docker container this error coming out :

```
MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/cme_api/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:309:9)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:536:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:480:7) {
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  reason: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1136:16) {
    name: 'MongoNetworkError',
    [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm not very familiar with those technologies and I don't understand what is going on.

Here is my database.js :

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
require('dotenv').config()

class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.client = null;
    }
    connect() {
        mongo.connect(process.env.URL_DATABASE, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
            if (err) throw err
            this.client = client;
        });
    }
}



const db = new Database();
db.connect();
module.exports = db;
```

And my app.js :

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express();
os = require('os');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const router = require('./router.js')
require('dotenv').config()


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/v1', router);

const port = (process.env.PORT || '3001');

let server = app.listen(port, os.hostname(), () => {
    let host = server.address().address,
        port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

If anyone can help me with this 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error means you don't have the database running in your container. If you only put the application in the container without the database, this would happen.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would communicate with the database through the URI

Comment: How exactly do you put the database in the container? I'm a bit lost here

Comment: While in principle you can, you typically wouldn't. Typically you would adjust the URI to match wherever the database is. The point is you wouldn't use `localhost` in the container unless the database is in fact *in* the container.

Comment: And to state for avoidance of doubt, `localhost` in the container refers to the container, not to the host system.